# Where can I download the OpenShift 4 CodeReady Containers VirtualBox crcbundle file?

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, openshift-client-tools, openshift-enterprise, openshift-4

I am trying to install Openshift4 locally on my computer and I am missing a file with the .crcbundle-extension. Could someone help me out on where to find this file or how to create it?

I am talking about the following project on github:
https://github.com/code-ready/crc#documentation

Cheers

Answer (score 3):

You can download the latest crc binaries [here](https://mirror.openshift.com/pub/openshift-v4/clients/crc/latest)

You also need a Red Hat developer account to run `crc` as it requires you to log in to https://cloud.redhat.com/openshift/install/crc/installer-provisioned to get a "pull secret" to deploy the cluster.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that support for VirtualBox in CRC has been removed (Refs: ['crc setup -d virtualbox' - driver flag is ignored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59337100/crc-setup-d-virtualbox-driver-flag-is-ignored) , https://github.com/code-ready/crc/issues/838 )

The link referenced by @nick doesn't provide the actual VirtualBox bundle file required. So far as I can tell, there does not appear to be any place to download the referenced VirtualBox bundle file.