# 'crc setup -d virtualbox' - driver flag is ignored

Tags: macos, openshift

I'm trying to setup crc on my mac os laptop:

```
$ crc setup --help
Set up local virtualization and networking infrastructure for the OpenShift cluster

Usage:
  crc setup [flags]

Flags:
  -h, --help               help for setup
  -d, --vm-driver string   The driver to use for the OpenShift cluster. Possible values: [hyperkit virtualbox] (default "hyperkit")
  ...
```

However, it seems the flag is ignored and it attempts to setup HyperKit:

```
$ crc setup -d virtualbox
INFO Checking if running as non-root
INFO Caching oc binary
INFO Setting up virtualization with HyperKit
...
```

The crc version:

```
$ crc version
crc version: 1.2.0+c2e3c0f
OpenShift version: 4.2.8 (embedded in binary)
```

My mac is version:

```
$ sw_vers
ProductName:    Mac OS X
ProductVersion: 10.14.6
BuildVersion:   18G95
```

Any idea why the crc `-d` flag is ignored and it sets up crc with Hyperkit?

Answer (score 3):

Support for VirtualBox was removed https://github.com/code-ready/crc/issues/838